# SignalR skipNegotiation not working on WPF Webview2

Tags: wpf, signalr, .net-6.0, webview2

I have implemented signalR code with skipNegotiation set to true in my web app. When opened from desktop browsers, it is working fine. But not working while opening on WPF WebView2.

[image]

This should work same as it is working in browser